# How do I define a specific, custom tuple type in EdgeDB?

Tags: tuples, edgedb

I would like to define a tuple of two numbers as below:

```
scalar type container extending tuple<int16, int16> {
  constraint expression on (
      __subject__.0 >= 0
      and __subject__.1 >= 0
      and __subject__.0 < 256
      and __subject__.1 < 256
      and __subject__.0 <= __subject__.1
    )
}
```

Is this possible?

I would prefer this over defining a full object type, because I am hoping a tuple type will also serialize to a tuple type in my programming language (TypeScript and Rust), while an object would serialize to an interface/struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 4.2 it's not possible to extend the `tuple`.
Most you can do is to use a constrained `int` inside of the tuple:

```
module default {

    scalar type uint8 extending int16 {
        constraint max_value(255);
        constraint min_value(0);
    }

    type WithTuple {
        container: tuple<uint8, uint8>;

        constraint expression on (
            .container.0 <= .container.1
        ) { errmessage := 'container start must be <= the container end' };

   }
}
```

Inserting a value gives a custom error:

```
insert WithTuple { container := (1, 0) };

# ConstraintViolationError: container start must be <= the container end
```

Alternatively, you can use [`range`](https://www.edgedb.com/docs/stdlib/range#constructing-ranges) which funny enough by default watches the lower bound to be less than the upper, but is not able to constraint the min/max, so we must do it explicitly:

```
module default {

    type WithRange {
        container: range<int32>; # Note: int16 is not supported for range
        
        constraint expression on (
            0 <= range_get_lower(.container) and range_get_upper(.container) <= 255
        ) { errmessage := 'range values must be 0 at minimum and 255 at maximum' };
    }
}
```

Here the `start <= end` invariant has default error message.

```
insert WithRange { container := range(1, 0) };

# InvalidValueError: range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound
```

And we can see that the custom one works too:

```
insert WithRange { container := range(-1, 0) };

# ConstraintViolationError: range values must be 0 at minimum and 255 at maximum
```

Note that since range is not overloaded with `int16`, but it is with `int32`, we might try to define our `uint8` as:

```
    scalar type uint8_32 extending int32 {
        constraint min_value(0);
        constraint max_value(255);
    }
```

But we would discover, that range won't accept that:

```
    type WithRange {
        container: range<uint8_32>;
    }
```

Here running `edgedb migration create` yields:

```
edgedb error: UnsupportedFeatureError: unsupported range subtype: default::uint8_32
```

Sadly, the `range` does not satisfy your need to serialize to tuple. With `range` in TypeScript you get the

```
import { Range } from "edgedb"

// simplified
type Range<T extends number | Date | LocalDate | LocalDateTime | Duration> {  
  lower: T | null;
  upper: T | null;
  inc_lower: boolean;
  inc_upper: boolean;
  empty?: undefined;
}
```

Still this might be an interesting option, given the possibility of an empty range.